# Is there a Google Sheets QUERY or Apps Script for assigning text to a number within a number range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of average scores for multiple projects. I would like to assign text to these scores based on where the average scores fall within a specified number range.

DATA SET

| Ref.No. | Avg.Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.9 |
| 2 | 6.3 |
| 3 | 7.5 |
| 4 | 9.7 |
| 5 | 12.5 |

NUMBER RANGE CATEGORIES

```
0 - 3.74    N/A
3.75 - 7.4  Poor
7.5 - 11.24 Adequate
11.25 - 15.9    Very Good
>15         Excellent
```

**DESIRED DATA SET**

| Ref.No. | Avg.Score | **Category** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.9 | Poor |
| 2 | 6.3 | Poor |
| 3 | 7.5 | Adequate |
| 4 | 9.7 | Adequate |
| 5 | 12.5 | Very Good |

I can create a pivot table and nested IF statements, but it's messy. VLOOKUP won't work since I'm looking for a number within a number range, not a specific number. Is there a way to use QUERY or create an Apps Script to make this work?

Comment: look into `MATCH` formula documentation. `VLOOKUP` will also work(with TRUE as last parameter). You just need to format the table in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheMaster mentioned in a comment, you can continue using VLOOKUP while making sure that the Range where the categories are located is sorted, this way you can use the `is_sorted` flag and the formula will return the best match.

As per Google's Doc:

> Use an approximate match or is_sorted = TRUE when you search for a best match, but not an exact match.
> If you want to search ID = 102, which doesn’t exist in the table, an approximate match takes one step back to give you ID = 101 as the result. This is because in the search key column, 101 is the closest value that is also less than 102.

The same applies for `MATCH`, for example:

```js
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$1:$I$5,MATCH(B2,$H$1:$H$5,TRUE)),"")
```

```js
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$H$1:$I$5,2,TRUE),"")
```

In this setup:

[image]

---

Google Docs Editors Help - [approximate match and why the data needs to be sorted.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318#Vlookupexactorapproximatetitle&zippy=%2Cexplanation)